# How to get more than one of this element on one page (w/ codepen)

Tags: javascript, html, css, codepen

I am creating a website right now (customizing a theme) and I want to use this element (https://codepen.io/ettrics/pen/qaXVAd) on one page.

Since I don't have much knowledge of html and css (enough to customize a bit) I can't get it to let me use more than one on one page.

I just want 3 of them next to each other.

Tried customizing a bit, heard something about children but don't know how to do that by myself.

That's the html, rest is on the codpen link:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container chart" data-size="400" data-value="88" data-arrow="up">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you so much Obisidian Age, that works like a charm! :) You rally helped me, hope you have an awesome day :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you'll want to clone out the HTML `<div>` element for the graph twice, so that there are three total dials:

```
<div class="container chart" data-size="400" data-value="88" data-arrow="up">
<div class="container chart" data-size="400" data-value="88" data-arrow="up">
<div class="container chart" data-size="400" data-value="88" data-arrow="up">
```

Second, you'll want to change `width: 400px` on `.wrapper` to `width: auto`, so that the elements can sit next to one another in a row.

Third, you'll want to change the JavaScript:

```
var dial = new Dial(containers[0]);
dial.animateStart();
```

...to create two new dial elements for `.chart` indexes `1` and `2`.

This can be done as a loop, though is most simply done with:

```
var dial1 = new Dial(containers[0]);
dial1.animateStart();
var dial2 = new Dial(containers[1]);
dial2.animateStart();
var dial3 = new Dial(containers[2]);
dial3.animateStart();
```

All of this can be seen in the following:

```js
//
// Library
//

var Dial = function(container) {
  this.container = container;
  this.size = this.container.dataset.size;
  this.strokeWidth = this.size / 8;
  this.radius = (this.size / 2) - (this.strokeWidth / 2);
  this.value = this.container.dataset.value;
  this.direction = this.container.dataset.arrow;
  this.svg;
  this.defs;
  this.slice;
  this.overlay;
  this.text;
  this.arrow;
  this.create();
}

Dial.prototype.create = function() {
  this.createSvg();
  this.createDefs();
  this.createSlice();
  this.createOverlay();
  this.createText();
  this.createArrow();
  this.container.appendChild(this.svg);
};

Dial.prototype.createSvg = function() {
  var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
  svg.setAttribute('width', this.size + 'px');
  svg.setAttribute('height', this.size + 'px');
  this.svg = svg;
};

Dial.prototype.createDefs = function() {
  var defs = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "defs");
  var linearGradient = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "linearGradient");
  linearGradient.setAttribute('id', 'gradient');
  var stop1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "stop");
  stop1.setAttribute('stop-color', '#6E4AE2');
  stop1.setAttribute('offset', '0%');
  linearGradient.appendChild(stop1);
  var stop2 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "stop");
  stop2.setAttribute('stop-color', '#78F8EC');
  stop2.setAttribute('offset', '100%');
  linearGradient.appendChild(stop2);
  var linearGradientBackground = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "linearGradient");
  linearGradientBackground.setAttribute('id', 'gradient-background');
  var stop1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "stop");
  stop1.setAttribute('stop-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)');
  stop1.setAttribute('offset', '0%');
  linearGradientBackground.appendChild(stop1);
  var stop2 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "stop");
  stop2.setAttribute('stop-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)');
  stop2.setAttribute('offset', '100%');
  linearGradientBackground.appendChild(stop2);
  defs.appendChild(linearGradient);
  defs.appendChild(linearGradientBackground);
  this.svg.appendChild(defs);
  this.defs = defs;
};

Dial.prototype.createSlice = function() {
  var slice = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
  slice.setAttribute('fill', 'none');
  slice.setAttribute('stroke', 'url(#gradient)');
  slice.setAttribute('stroke-width', this.strokeWidth);
  slice.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + this.strokeWidth / 2 + ',' + this.strokeWidth / 2 + ')');
  slice.setAttribute('class', 'animate-draw');
  this.svg.appendChild(slice);
  this.slice = slice;
};

Dial.prototype.createOverlay = function() {
  var r = this.size - (this.size / 2) - this.strokeWidth / 2;
  var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
  circle.setAttribute('cx', this.size / 2);
  circle.setAttribute('cy', this.size / 2);
  circle.setAttribute('r', r);
  circle.setAttribute('fill', 'url(#gradient-background)');
  this.svg.appendChild(circle);
  this.overlay = circle;
};

Dial.prototype.createText = function() {
  var fontSize = this.size / 3.5;
  var text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
  text.setAttribute('x', (this.size / 2) + fontSize / 7.5);
  text.setAttribute('y', (this.size / 2) + fontSize / 4);
  text.setAttribute('font-family', 'Century Gothic, Lato');
  text.setAttribute('font-size', fontSize);
  text.setAttribute('fill', '#78F8EC');
  text.setAttribute('text-anchor', 'middle');
  var tspanSize = fontSize / 3;
  text.innerHTML = 0 + '<tspan font-size="' + tspanSize + '" dy="' + -tspanSize * 1.2 + '">%</tspan>';
  this.svg.appendChild(text);
  this.text = text;
};

Dial.prototype.createArrow = function() {
  var arrowSize = this.size / 10;
  var arrowYOffset, m;
  if (this.direction === 'up') {
    arrowYOffset = arrowSize / 2;
    m = -1;
  } else if (this.direction === 'down') {
    arrowYOffset = 0;
    m = 1;
  }
  var arrowPosX = ((this.size / 2) - arrowSize / 2);
  var arrowPosY = (this.size - this.size / 3) + arrowYOffset;
  var arrowDOffset = m * (arrowSize / 1.5);
  var arrow = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
  arrow.setAttribute('d', 'M 0 0 ' + arrowSize + ' 0 ' + arrowSize / 2 + ' ' + arrowDOffset + ' 0 0 Z');
  arrow.setAttribute('fill', '#97F8F0');
  arrow.setAttribute('opacity', '0.6');
  arrow.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + arrowPosX + ',' + arrowPosY + ')');
  this.svg.appendChild(arrow);
  this.arrow = arrow;
};

Dial.prototype.animateStart = function() {
  var v = 0;
  var self = this;
  var intervalOne = setInterval(function() {
    var p = +(v / self.value).toFixed(2);
    var a = (p < 0.95) ? 2 - (2 * p) : 0.05;
    v += a;
    // Stop
    if (v >= +self.value) {
      v = self.value;
      clearInterval(intervalOne);
    }
    self.setValue(v);
  }, 10);
};

Dial.prototype.animateReset = function() {
  this.setValue(0);
};

Dial.prototype.polarToCartesian = function(centerX, centerY, radius, angleInDegrees) {
  var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees - 90) * Math.PI / 180.0;
  return {
    x: centerX + (radius * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
    y: centerY + (radius * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
  };
}

Dial.prototype.describeArc = function(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {
  var start = this.polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, endAngle);
  var end = this.polarToCartesian(x, y, radius, startAngle);
  var largeArcFlag = endAngle - startAngle <= 180 ? "0" : "1";
  var d = [
    "M", start.x, start.y,
    "A", radius, radius, 0, largeArcFlag, 0, end.x, end.y
  ].join(" ");
  return d;
}

Dial.prototype.setValue = function(value) {
  var c = (value / 100) * 360;
  if (c === 360)
    c = 359.99;
  var xy = this.size / 2 - this.strokeWidth / 2;
  var d = this.describeArc(xy, xy, xy, 180, 180 + c);
  this.slice.setAttribute('d', d);
  var tspanSize = (this.size / 3.5) / 3;
  this.text.innerHTML = Math.floor(value) + '<tspan font-size="' + tspanSize + '" dy="' + -tspanSize * 1.2 + '">%</tspan>';
};

//
// Usage
//

var containers = document.getElementsByClassName("chart");
var dial1 = new Dial(containers[0]);
dial1.animateStart();
var dial2 = new Dial(containers[1]);
dial2.animateStart();
var dial3 = new Dial(containers[2]);
dial3.animateStart();
```

```css
body {
  background: #18222F;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container chart" data-size="400" data-value="88" data-arrow="down">
    </div>
    <div class="container chart" data-size="400" data-value="88" data-arrow="up">
    </div>
    <div class="container chart" data-size="400" data-value="88" data-arrow="up">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your markup to have more `container` divs, like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container chart" data-size="400" data-value="88" data-arrow="up"></div>
  <div class="container chart" data-size="400" data-value="88" data-arrow="up"></div>
  <div class="container chart" data-size="400" data-value="88" data-arrow="up"></div>
</div>
```

...then the code that selects containers will add them to the `containers` list, and you can put dials in them (and animate the dials) the same way you did in the first container, like:

```
var dial = new Dial(containers[0]);
var dial2 = new Dial(containers[1]);
var dial3 = new Dial(containers[2]);

dial.animateStart();
dial2.animateStart();
dial3.animateStart();
```